# How do make the buttons in a fragment manipulate integer variables in seperate activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is a rudimentary android application that serves as an umpires strike/ball/out counter. There is a settings icon in the action bar of the MainActivity. When this icon is 'clicked on', a new Activity is started consisting of a PreferenceFragment, which consists of a checkboxpreference, and a Fragment that consists of 3 buttons. These buttons reset the stike_count, ball_count and total_outs_count to zero. I have spent a day on this and am having trouble figuring out how to manipulate integer variables in my MainActivity from button clicks in a separate Activity's Fragment. Please point me in the right direction.

```
MyApplication class
////////////////////////////////////////////////

package edu.umkc.baldwin;

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private int strikes, balls, outs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        strikes = 0;
        balls = 0;
        outs = 0;
    }

    public void setStrikeCount(int strike_c){
        this.strikes = strike_c;
    }
    public void setBallCount(int ball_c){
        this.balls = ball_c;
    }
    public void setOutsCount(int out_c){
        this.outs = out_c;
    }
    public int getStrikeCount(){
        return strikes;
    }
    public int getBallCount(){
        return balls;
    }
    public int getOutCount(){
        return outs;
    }

}


MainActivity
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


package edu.umkc.baldwin;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/*
 *   MainAcitvity extends the Activity class and provides all the functionality
 *   of the homescreen (main_page_layout) widgets including the actionbar items and presumably the 
 *   menu button on the bottom left of the device (on most devices). 
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "UmpireActivity";

    MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();

    TextView strikeCounterTV;
    TextView ballCounterTV;
    TextView totalOutCounterTV;

    private Button strikeCounterButton;
    private Button ballCounterButton;

    private int strike_count;
    private int ball_count;
    private int out_count;

    /*
     *    Method to update the TextViews representing balls,
     *    outs and strikes
     */
    public void updateViews(){
        strikeCounterTV.setText(String.valueOf(strike_count));
        ballCounterTV.setText(String.valueOf(ball_count));
        totalOutCounterTV.setText(String.valueOf(out_count));
    }

    /*
     *    Method to display a Toast message to the user when 
     *    strikes have reached 3 or balls have reached 4
     */
    private void displayToast(boolean x){
        int messageId = 0;
        if (x == true){
            messageId = R.string.strike_toast_view;
        } else {
            messageId = R.string.ball_toast_view;
        }
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, messageId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        LinearLayout toastLayout = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
        TextView toastTV = (TextView) toastLayout.getChildAt(0);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, -150);
        toastTV.setTextSize(42);
        toast.show();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate(Bundle) called");
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page_layout);

        strikeCounterTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.strikeCountTextView);
        ballCounterTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ballCountTextView);
        totalOutCounterTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalOutsTextViewCounter);

        strikeCounterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.strikeCountButton);
        ballCounterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ballCountButton);

        strikeCounterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (strike_count < 2){
                    strike_count++;
                    updateViews();
                } else {                   
                    // batter has reached strike limit
                    displayToast(true);
                    out_count++;
                    strike_count = 0;
                    ball_count = 0;
                    updateViews();
                }
            }
        });
        ballCounterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ball_count < 3){
                    ball_count++;
                    updateViews();
                } else {                   
                    // batter has reached ball limit
                    displayToast(false);
                    strike_count = 0;
                    ball_count = 0;
                    updateViews();
                }
            }
        });

        // http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html
        SharedPreferences savedObject = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        out_count = savedObject.getInt("outs_key", 0);
        strike_count = savedObject.getInt("strikes_key", 0);
        ball_count = savedObject.getInt("balls_key", 0);
        updateViews();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState() called");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Displays actionbar items in app actionbar
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_layout, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case (R.id.about_menu_option): 
                Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            case (R.id.reset_option):
                strike_count = 0;
                ball_count = 0;
                updateViews();
                return true;
            case (R.id.settings_menu_option):
                Intent j = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(j);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");

        app.setStrikeCount(strike_count);

        // SHOULD THIS CODE BE IN onPause()
        // OR onStop()  ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????
                // store value of out_count to restore after application exit
                // http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html
                SharedPreferences out_file = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = out_file.edit();
                editor.putInt("outs_key", out_count);
                editor.putInt("strikes_key", strike_count);
                editor.putInt("balls_key", ball_count);
                editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
        // Save 'totalOuts' variable through application exit
        // http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html
        SharedPreferences savedObject = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        out_count = savedObject.getInt("outs_key", 0);
        strike_count = savedObject.getInt("strikes_key", 0);
        ball_count = savedObject.getInt("balls_key", 0);
        updateViews();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
    }
}











SettingsActivity
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

package edu.umkc.baldwin;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_layout);

        FragmentManager ttsFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ttsFragmentTransaction = ttsFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        EnableTTSPreferenceFragment ttsFragment = new EnableTTSPreferenceFragment();
        ttsFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.tts_fragment, ttsFragment);
        ttsFragmentTransaction.commit();

        FragmentManager resetFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction resetFragmentTransaction = resetFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ResetFragment resetFragment = new ResetFragment();
        resetFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.reset_fragment, resetFragment);
        resetFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}


ResetFragment
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

package edu.umkc.baldwin;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ResetFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View resetFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reset_layout, container, false); 
        return resetFragment;
    }
}


EnableTTSPreferenceFragment
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

package edu.umkc.baldwin;  
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class EnableTTSPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.tts_preference_fragment);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);    
    }   
}


Android manifest file
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.umkc.baldwin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/umpire_buddy_icon"
        android:name="edu.umkc.baldwin.MyApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="edu.umkc.baldwin.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>  
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="edu.umkc.baldwin.About"
            android:parentActivityName="edu.umkc.baldwin.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/about_menu_text" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="edu.umkc.baldwin.Settings"
            android:parentActivityName="edu.umkc.baldwin.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings_text" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="edu.umkc.baldwin.SettingsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="edu.umkc.baldwin.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings_text" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Extend Application object and save the strike count values in that. All the activities have  access to it. Update it from settings and the main activity will be able to see the change as well.
2. When you start the setting activity, do startActivityForResult and make the setting activity return a result, which you can use to update your counts.

Comment: I tried solution #1 which makes sense to me, however, after making the MyApplication class (extending Application) I CANNOT use the getter and setter methods of that class. I get the error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate acitvity ComponentInfo{edu.umkc.baldwin/edu.umkc.baldwin.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException      Declaring the Application object: MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication(); works fine but when I try: app.getStrikeCount(); I get that error

Comment: @PeterBaldwin have you updated the application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml with your custom class ? If already done,please share the relevant code from the MainActivity

Comment: I have updated the manifest file to no avail. I have included the manifest.xml in the question code! Any other suggestions??  thanks for the help

Comment: @PeterBaldwin could you update the question with the latest code and stacktrace

Comment: So I couldn't post an image of the Logcat (is that the same as the stack track?) because I do not have enough reputation points but here are the errors I am getting :  FATAL EXECPTION: main \n java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity (edu.umkc.baldwin/edu.umkc.baldwin.MainActivity): java.lang.NullPointerException. I have also updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `Fragments` are in context of a particular `Activity` and **public methods in the activity** can be accessed like `getActivity().methodName()`.

Now If you want to change any data that has to be changed from the fragment then you may go by any of these two approaches :

- From your `fragment` call a public method of you base `activity` and within that public method you can get the context of `MainActivity` and change its **public variables.**
- I am not sure about the design or flow of your application but will recommend to create **static variables and access and modify them using class names easily**

Answer (score 0):

Use Application class to solve this. Here is an example code for this solution:

**1. Create the Application Class.**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private int strike_count, ball_count, out_count;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //initialize the variables here
        strike_count = 0;
        ball_count = 0;
        out_count = 0;
    }

    // create set and get functions

    public void setStrikeCount(int strike_count) {
        this.strike_count = strike_count;
    }

    public void setBallCount(int ball_count) {
        this.ball_count = ball_count;
    }

    public void setOutCount(int out_count) {
        this.out_count = out_count;
    }

    public int getStrikeCount() {
        return strike_count;
    }

    public int getBallCount() {
        return ball_count;
    }

    public int getOutCount() {
        return out_count;
    }
}
```

**2. Mention this Application class in your manifest file.**

```
<application android:name="yourpackagename.MyApplication"/>
```

**3. Access the application object in any activity by using the following code.**

```
MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
```

After you get this done, you can manipulate these variables in any activity by simply using any of the Application's public function such as:

```
app.setStrikeCount(10);
```

Comment: That makes sense to me, however, after making the MyApplication class (extending Application):

Comment: That makes sense to me, however, after making the MyApplication class (extending Application) I CANNOT use the getter and setter methods of that class. I get the error:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate acitvity ComponentInfo{edu.umkc.baldwin/edu.umkc.baldwin.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Declaring the Application object: MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();  works fine but when I try: app.getStrikeCount(); I get that error

Comment: Have you put `<application android:name="edu.umkc.baldwin.MyApplication"/>` in your project's manifest file?

Comment: I did include the android:name att in the <application> tag. Still crashes when I try to call one of the MyApplication methods!!!!  AARRGGG Thank you so much for the help, I can see that once I get this design to work that changing the variable will be much easier! Any other suggestions ???

Comment: I have updated the code. Is there anything that you see i am doing wrong @simplebe

Comment: You need to initialize your variables in `onCreate()` function at your MainActivity class. In your updated code above, you just updated your `strike_count` only when strikeCounterButton or ballCounterButton has been clicked.

Comment: I believe your app crashed due to `app.setStrikeCount(strike_count)` is not working. I assumes `strike_count` does not have any value in it at this point since you got 'Unable to pause activity' and 'NullPointerException' from the errors you are getting.